# Change order before returning data

Tags: function, plugins, solr

Is there any way to change order of result in SOLR.
E.g when I query in SOLR i will get 1000 records with highest score, then in those 1000 records I will use my own function to change order again and just get 10 records of those records.

I can get 1000 records and process by php or java, but I have to transfer 1000 records from SOLR server to webserver and I dont want that, I just want to get 10 records after changing order and use paging.

Is SOLR support this kind of custom function?

Answer (score 0):

If you function can be applied when the records are initially indexed, you can do it there and add the result as a value on the record.  Then sort the result set by the precalculated value.  If not, i haven't worked with it directly, but [this thread](http://www.mail-archive.com/solr-user@lucene.apache.org/msg05501.html) seems to have the answer you're looking for

Comment: Hi 
My case is very special, I had preindex score in database already.

Comment: Hi 
My case is very special, I had preindex score in database already. Let me give one example, I have shopping site, when I search for TV LCD 32 inch, I got many result from some different branch like LG, Toshiba ... and may result for LG appear consequently I want to separate it e.g I dont want 3 results for LG sit next together, Currently I get 1000 best records (base on score) and change the order again using PHP, now I want to move this job to SOLR (I dont want transfer data to much between SOLR and Webserver, I just need 10 records to display)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create a column with the info you want to be taken into account into the score. For ex, for a "popularity" column, your query would be:

```
your query && _val_:"popularity"^0.7
```

0.7 being the boost factor into the final score.
you can also filter the result set to get less results:

```
your query && fq=popularity:[10 TO *]
```